# Would a thread handling a subsequent network request be guaranteed to see the value of a volatile variable written during a previous request?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have this theoretical question about the Java Memory Model. Suppose I have a server with these two request handlers in the following class:

```
class MyHandlers {
  volatile int someFlag = 0;

  String handleFirstRequest() {
    someFlag = 1;
    return "Hello!";
  }

  String handleSecondRequest() {
    return "value of someFlag: " + someFlag;
  }
}
```

I also have a client. My client sends a network request that triggers executing handleFirstRequest. The client waits until the request completes. Once the first request completes, the client sends the second request that triggers handleSecondRequest.

**Question:** How does the Java Memory Model prevent the response to the second request from being `"value of someFlag: 0"`?

Notes: I understand that, in practice, the thread handling the second response will always see `someFlag` as 1.

If I read the JMM correctly, there is a synchronization order that is a total order, which would order the volatile read and the volatile write (`someFlag = 1`) in my example. If the read is subsequent to the write, then the read will see the write. Is it possible to have a case where the write is subsequent to the read? In this case, the write does not synchronizes-with the read, and there would be no happens-before relationship between the write and the read. This would lead the thread handling the second request to see `someFlag` as 0. Where does my understanding go wrong?

**Additional thoughts (2020 Mar 2):** The JMM does not refer to the concept of time. Synchronization actions are ordered according to synchronization order, but nothing in the JMM says that synchronization order is the same as order of actions sorted by time. This suggests a Java implementation may order the read of `someFlag` **before** the write even though the read occurred **after** the write according to the clock. It seems like the JMM only guarantees that **if** the volatile read is ordered after the volatile write, then writes before the volatile write are visible to reads after the volatile read.

Comment: Using a volatile variable does not guarantee that any write happens before the reads. Of course, if a thread first reads the value, and _afterwards_ another thread writes a value to the variable, the first thread cannot read the new value. Volatile simply guarantess that any read will always see the last written value!

Comment: "How does the Java Memory Model prevent the response to the second request from being "value of someFlag: 0"? - It does not. It only guarantees that you always see the last value, which can be 0 or 1, or anything else. But, if you ALWAYS send the second request after the first one, you can say that the value will always be 1, since the second request happens after the first one.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks! That is my understanding of volatiles as well. I suppose I am trying to reconcile that understanding with my understanding of the JMM. The JMM does not include a concept of time. For example, what would "last written value" mean in the JMM? I thought of another way to phrase my question: Suppose thread A writes a 1 to a volatile variable (initially 0) at time T. Thread B reads from the volatile at time T+1. The JMM does not guarantee that thread B will read a 1 from the volatile; the JMM actually allows thread B to read a 0. Is this correct?

Comment: Re, "...no concept of time." The "happens before" thing _is_ the JMM's concept of time. But, as you may have noticed, it's limited. In this case though, you have additional knowledge that the JMM does not have. _You_ know that the client won't send the second request until after it has received the reply to the first request. You must combine what _you_ know with what the JMM promises in order to prove that the handler for the second request will see `someFlag==1`. Sometimes you don't have enough information... When that happens, we say that your program depends on a "data race."

Comment: Yes, but how do we know that the happens-before order is a subset of the ordering of the actions when the actions are ordered by time? Also, how would the JMM account for ordering relationships outside of the JVM? If the JMM actually does include external happens-before relationships as part of the model, then the usage of volatile would be unnecessary since the happens-before order is transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer!

[Section 17.4.3 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) states the following:

> Sequential consistency is a very strong guarantee that is made about visibility and ordering in an execution of a program. Within a sequentially consistent execution, there is a total order over all individual actions (such as reads and writes) which is consistent with the order of the program, and each individual action is atomic and is **immediately visible to every thread**.

In the Java Memory model, "actions" refer to inter-thread actions, which include volatile writes. This paragraph guarantees that any Java implementation that conforms to the JLS guarantees that volatile writes will be immediately visible to other threads. In the example in the opening post, this paragraph guarantees that the volatile read can not be ordered before the volatile write.

Answer (score 2):

If the first request completes then it means that `someFlag = 1` has been executed by some thread. At that point the value of someFlag is guaranted to be visible by any other threads performing read. So when the second request comes you can be sure that it will see value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, each thread has its own cache somewhere in the hardware. Reads and writes are normally did in this cache and at some later time (when the memory lines need to leave the cache), are written back into the main memory. This is the reason why two different threads might see different values for the same variable.

The `volatile` keyword prevents that. A `volatile` value is never cached and all of the reads and writes must be done in the main memory. As a bonus, the `volatile` value is also atomically read and written.

So, when the first thread updates the `someFlag` to 1, it is made visible to all threads instantly (at the cost of a lower perfomance due to caching-prevention). Then, when the second thread reads it, it will see the value given by the first thread.

Since the client waits for the completion of the first request to start the second, you established that the first request happens-before the second one.

Summing all of that, there would be no way for the second request to see `someFlag` as 0.

Answer (score -1):

In your description,you send request2 after request1 completed,so request2 is certein get `someFlag = 1`。

---

In another situation：thread A has just started handleFirstRequest() yet finished when thread B come to read the `someFlag`，B will get `someFlag = 0`。

Yes,it could be，but with a very very slim possibility...

In JMM,there are 8 atomic operations you may have read：

- lock \ unlock
- read \ write
- load \ store
- use \ assign

Yes each JMM operation has atomicity feature but ,they can not be one atomic within ordered JMM executions。If thread want to alter `someFlag`，he will read -- load -- em... and a lot of jmm operations，all the seperated operations do not hava atomicity。

---

And what volatile do? it use `CAS` to prevent Multi-thread conflict and ennable `Bus` could perceive any JMM write operation and then invalidate field which been written in all thread have read。When a loaded field is invalid，thread will update it immediately。

Comment: You could point out my mistake and veto me(that's acceptable)，Don't be a mouse using a simple click.

Comment: Hi @TenkFish! Thank you for your answer. I did not downvote your answer, but I think the answer is dependent on details about the Java implementation. As unlikely as it seems, volatile may be implemented differently in a different implementation. Consider an _evil_ Java implementation that tries to subvert our expectations of Java, while still conforming to the behavior specified by the Java Language Specification (JLS). Is there some property given by the JMM or elsewhere in the JLS that guarantees `someFlag` will be 1? Your answer suggests that there is no guarantee, right?

Comment: I didn't downvoted you, but B will never get `someFlag = 0` exactly because it is `volatile`. So, your answer seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Victor Stafusa B will never get `someFlag=0` exactly because This Question send B after A completed，it's no business with `volatile`。

Comment: @Alex W  oblivious No..。But if you want to B retrive `someFlag=0` you could send them as the same time